# How to flush the input serial buffer in Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I am communicating with the esp8266 WiFi module using Arduino. The module returns GET requests from other clients. They will be of the form

```
GET /101011 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost...
```

I wish to extract only the `101011` from the received serial data and discard the rest. I came up with this small chunk of code to test it by sending data from my laptop.

This is the code:

```
String s;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if(Serial.available())
  {
    Serial.println("Inside");
    Serial.find("/");
    s = Serial.readStringUntil(' ');
    Serial.println(s);
    // Discard the rest of the data . Snippet from Jeremy Blum's Blog

    while(Serial.available()>0) Serial.read(); 

  }

}
```

[Jeremy's Blog](http://www.jeremyblum.com/2011/02/07/arduino-tutorial-6-serial-communication-and-processing/)

But when I run this using the input `GET /101011 HTTP/1.1\r\n` the output produced is

```
Inside
101011
Inside
1.1\r\n
```

Why is `Serial.available()` returning `true` even after reading everything? How to discard the rest of data from the serial input buffer?

Comment: How do you know you have read everything? Serial data is still arriving from the ESP8266 while you are clearing the buffer - and you are clearing it much faster than the data is arriving.  Remember: serial data arrives *s...l...o...w...l...y...*

Comment: Read this:~ https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/

Comment: @Majenko Thank you. Read your blog. Will try to implement it in my design.

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to read and discard everything for a fixed time, like a second. For example:

```C++
unsigned long now = millis ();
while (millis () - now < 1000)
  Serial.read ();  // read and discard any input
```

I'm not a big fan of trying to "flush the input buffer". How do you know if a second is long enough? Or maybe it is too long? You are better off reading to some known delimiter.